# Template variable input type IMAGE but WebP file

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution

I optimised my images and converted them into WebP format... image.webp

It seems to improve page speed significantly.

However, I have a template-variable IMAGE [*blogpost-image*] defined.
Now with this .webp extension (= Chrome HTML document), I cannot open the IMAGES directory and add the images to my resource docs. I tried changing the input type to URL and also to FILE for my template-variable, but none seems to work.

How can I get my images in .webp on front-end with a template variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the **System Settings**. Under **Area: File System** you should see the **Uploadable Image Type** setting (or similar depending on your MODX version). The default is a list of usual image file types: .jpg, .png etc. You probably need to add the .webp extension in order to upload those to the image browser.

Comment: @Llannotti - thanks, that was simple and logical enough. I just found out that webP has weak browser support, so thats why it didnt show. Hopefully I can find a way to display webP across ALL browsers. Any suggestions are welcomed?

Comment: Well that's a different question. Caniuse has some resources.  Personally, I would stick with image formats that do have good browser support.
http://caniuse.com/#search=webp